# как присвоить переменной значение возвращаемое функцией

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator

Нужно присвоить значение, которое возвращает функция при нажатии на кнопку. в окне пользователь вписывает значение в 4 LineEdit и при нажатии на кнопку функция производит расчет и в конечном итоге возвращает значение. нужно это значение присвоить в переменную вне функции, т.е. сюда

```
//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QtMath>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this)

varA = new QLineEdit;
varB = new QLineEdit;
varC = new QLineEdit;
varD = new QLineEdit;

doGraph = new QPushButton("graphs");

connect(doGraph, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(on_doGraph_clicked()));
connect(ui->varA, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(on_changed()));
connect(ui->varB, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(on_changed()));
connect(ui->varC, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(on_changed()));
connect(ui->varD, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(on_changed()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

функция:

```
double MainWindow::on_doGraph_clicked()
{
    double gamma1, xi1;
    double variableA = ui->varA->text().toDouble();
    double variableB = ui->varB->text().toDouble();
    double variableC = ui->varC->text().toDouble();
    double variableD = ui->varD->text().toDouble();

double sum1 = variableA + variableD;
double sum2 = variableA*variableD - variableB*variableC;

double disk = sum1 * sum1 - 4 * sum2;

if(disk>=0){
    gamma1 = (sum1 + sqrt(disk)) / 2;
    xi1 = (gamma1 - variableA) / variableB;

}
else{        
    return 0;
}
return xi1;
```

}

Простым присваиванием
`double v = on_doGraph_clicked();`
не работает

Comment: *"не работает"* не является описанием проблемы